# What does increase in weight of the sample on heating imply?

Tags: material-science

I have done TGA(Thermogravemetric analysis) of the sample and the result of the same shows that the % weight has increased for increase in certain range of temperature.Generally, the weight decreases on increasing the temperature which is due to decomposition of the sample.
However,I am getting an opposite behavior[image: This is the graph obtained]. How do we account for increase in %weight as temperature is increased in TGA ?

Comment: Are you doing it in air or in an inert gas?

Comment: we should look at bond energy of calcium ferrite ions.

Comment: I guess the process should be done in vacuum like conditions?

Comment: This comment is merely to encourage the use of plain English. "I measured the weight at various temperatures" is much clearer than "I have done thermogravimetric analysis".

Comment: The purging gas was N2

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your sample is oxidizing  while you are heating it. The sample gets heavier by pulling oxygen out of the atmosphere.